# How does kivy response to a click event?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to develop a Turing machine simulator with kivy and python and I got the basic GUI setup. But when I click the buttons in top bar and side bar the on_touch_down() function is sort of overload the on_press() function. How can I fix that?
So what I want is when I click anywhere in stage area, the on_touch_down() function is called and the coordinate is printed, and when I click any button the on_press() function is called and nothing is got printed.
Here is my code:

GUIDisplay.py

```
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import *

class RootWidget(FloatLayout):

    def add_transition_toggle(self):
        print 'something happened'

    def change_tape(self):
        pass

    def backgroundpress(self):
        print 'region'

    def actionbuttonpress(self):
        print 'menu'
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print touch.x, touch.y


class GUIDisplay(App):

    def build(self):
        app = RootWidget()
        return app


def start_app():
    GUIDisplay().run()

if '__main__' == __name__:
    start_app()
```

GUIDisplay.kv

```
<RootWidget>:
    # menu bar
    id: toolbars
    ActionBar:
        pos_hint: {'top':1}
        ActionView:
            use_separator: True
            ActionPrevious:
                text: ''
                title: 'Turing App'
                with_previous: False
            ActionGroup:
                text: 'File'
                mode: 'spinner'
                size_hint_x: None
                width: 90
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'New'
                    on_press: root.actionbuttonpress()
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Open'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Save'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Save As'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Quit'
            ActionGroup:
                text: 'Play'
                mode: 'spinner'
                size_hint_x: None
                width: 90
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Play to End'

    # tool bar
    BoxLayout:

        BoxLayout:
            y: 10.0
            x: 10.0
            height: 400.0
            width: 80.0
            size_hint_y: 0.9
            size_hint_x: 0.08
            orientation: 'vertical'
            opacity: 0.5
            Button:
                text: 'Select'
            Button:
                text: 'Add State'
            Button:
                text: 'Modify State'
            Button:
                on_release: root.add_transition_toggle()
                on_press: pass
                text: 'Add Transition'
            Button:
                text: 'Tape'
                on_release: root.change_tape()
        Label:
            text: 'Stage Area'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be the first to admit that this is ugly, so maybe someone else can find a better way. The problem as I understand it is that the RelativeLayout is digesting the touch event and therefore not passing it on down the widget tree. So you could try something along these lines to check if the children have digested it (was a button pressed) and if not, print the x, y coordinates.

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    event_handled = False
    for child in self.children:
        if not event_handled:
            if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
                event_handled = True

    if not event_handled:
        print touch.x, touch.y
```

Hopefully that helps...

Comment: Rather than the `event_handled` flag, you could simply `return` straight out of the loop. That would simplify things a bit.